# Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was "."

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

When I try to load the sample user page from the rails tutorial, I get this error:

> Showing
>   C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>   where line #5 raised: Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was
>   "."   (in
>   C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:113)

```
  <html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>
  true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with how the code is formatted, and I don't see what "." it's referring to.

Comment: Can you post custom.css.scss around line 108 to 118? The error message says it fails in C:/Sites/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:113

Comment: the error is in `custom.css.scss:113` not in `application.html.erb`. First look there, if you can't fix it post the contents.

Comment: Woops, looks like I was looking in the wrong place, thanks Lukas_Skywalker and p11y!